# How can I avoid very slow model build times when iterating on tests with Entity Framework Code First?

Tags: c#, testing

We are using EF code first with a rather large number of entities. The OnModelCreating() method in the DbContext can take 30-40 seconds to finish. This is fine for our application, but is very frustrating when trying to iterate on writing tests (these are tests which hit the database, not ones where we want to use LINQ to objects). Every time I kick off a singleton test as part of the debugging process, I have to wait for the EF model to be built.

Does anyone have any suggestions for increasing performance here?

We are using NUnit with EF 4.3.1, and are running tests with the Resharper NUnit runner in Visual Studio.